# Android Hourly Task View

Tags: android

I am developing an android app, which has a date picker, on data picked I want a list view, with 24 lists one for each hour, each of this lists should have another list view to show some lists of information to be done for that particular hour.
Is there any Library that i can use to achieve this? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Best library for hourly view](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View)after looking around a lot, i found the best solution.